# How do you calculate how heavy you feel from negative g forces?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, acceleration, weight

My physics tacher told me that to calculate the weight that you feel from negative g forces you have to devide your mass by the negative g force, but then my friend told me that it did't make sense and now I'm confused...
Please help!

Comment: Is [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/504044/) your friend?

Comment: Yeah, thats him!

Comment: Possible duplicate https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/504044/